# SQL Geometry return type

Tags: sql-server, geocoding, geography

In a sql query I can say

```
select * 
from location
where geoLocation.STDistance(0xE6100000010CDDB5847CD0EB42C033333333331F6240) < 10000
```

but how do I pass that 0xE61... bit in programatically.

when returning in from the database, it appears to be in a binary format. Thus just putting it into the query doesn't work. If I put it in as type binary it doesn't work either.

Is there a way to retrieve the Geolocation from the database that retains it in the above format, i've tried casting it to varchar but it ends up like POINT(....

Comment: So, you have these values in hexadecimal stored in the database, and you want to use them in your query, but can't compare it to 10000?

Comment: That is the format of 0xE6... is how SQL stores geometry. the 1000 is a distance in meters. You probably don't understand STDistance.

Comment: Well, actually I've never used it, nor did I kniw it is possible. I was just trying to understand your question and help.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean but you can pass it around as a GEOGRAPHY data type [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9900/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL has a bunch of static methods for creating geospatial data. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933802.aspx) out (specifically the OGC static and Extended static links). For example:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326);
SELECT @g.ToString();
```